# Are service URLs in apex rest service case sensitive?

Tags: rest-api, url

Rest API parameter are case-sensitive, Like User_Id and user_id are not interchangeable.
But are **services URLs also case-sensitive**?

Answer (score 5):

As per salesforce [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_rest_resource.htm):

> The URL mapping is case-sensitive. A URL mapping for my_url will only match a REST resource containing my_url and not My_Url.

Also if you are packaging your REST Service in a managed package your package namespace prefix is also case-sensitive.

> The URL for a namespaced classes contains the namespace. For example, if your class is in namespace abc and the class is mapped to your_url, then the API URL is modified as follows: https://instance.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/abc/your_url/. In the case of a URL collision, the namespaced class is always used.

In above example if your namespace is abc you can't use ABC, Abc or any other variation of upper/lower case namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I agree to Amit and its true about custom API.

But for standard API the URI are **case insensitive. (except the id part)**

For ex: send request to any of following uri and it still returns valid result

- /services/data/v35.0/sobjects/Account/0019000001AWn2oAAD
- /services/data/v35.0/sobjects/AccOunt/0019000001AWn2oAAD
- /services/data/v35.0/sobjects/ACCOUNT/0019000001AWn2oAAD

But if you try with case insensitive ID it will not work.
for ex.

- /services/data/v35.0/sobjects/Account/0019000001AWn2oAAd
- /services/data/v35.0/sobjects/AccOunt/0019000001aWn2oAAD
- /services/data/v35.0/sobjects/ACCOUNT/0019000001AWN2o

PS: for this simple test i used workbench but you can use any client and it should work

Comment: Sort of. If you mess up the case of an ID, salesforce tends to complain about it.

Comment: not for ids with length 18

Comment: Yes, even with IDs length 18. You'll get a MALFORMED_ID error if you change any single character's case in the ID. Try it out for yourself.

Comment: ok, got you point. Updated my answer.

Comment: @sfdcfox, thank you for the comment, it was helpful. Also this leads me to new question http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/130158/what-is-use-of-18-digit-of-id . Please take a look at it when you get time. Thanks.